# Printing a picture with the filename overlayed on top of it

Tags: windows-7, printing, pictures

Is there a way to ask Windows to print pictures with the filename overlayed on top of the picture? (e.g. in small print on the bottom left corner of the picture). If not what would be an application that would facilitate this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in Paint (Win+R, pbrush.exe)

ImageMagick can do that from command line if you need mass processing:
(Convert tool, "-annotate" or "-draw text" option.)
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#annotate

Command line loop in Windows:

```
for %i in (*.png *.jpg *.gif) do convert ... %i
```

Usually I make dry run before running actual loop:

```
for %i in (*.png *.jpg *.gif) do echo convert ... %i
```

Answer (score 2):

Two other options, although both print the filename *below* the picture, not overlayed on it.

- If you're willing to work with just thumbnail-size prints, Windows
  will print the picture with the filename at the `Contact sheet (35)`
  setting
- Or, create a PowerPoint Photo Album (Under `Insert`)

  1. select your photos
  2. Choose Picture Layout with anything ***other*** than the default Fit to Slide
  3. check `Captions below ALL pictures`